# How do I run a .bat file in powershell with nested .bat files?

Tags: windows, command-line, ssh, powershell, batch-file

I am currently remoting into a computer through SSH and need to start up a process that will not close when the SSH connection has been closed. For this I am using the cmdlet Invoke-WmiProcess.

But I am running into a unique problem. When I run the .bat file on the host computer. The .bat file cannot locate the other .bat files within the same directory. My thought is it has something to do with the working directory. But I can not figure out how to get this to change.

Comment: You can change the working directory using `cd`, just like in .bat files.

Comment: Use `call`[`"%~dp0other_batch_file.bat"`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) in the first batch file...

Comment: @LPChip It still doesn't work. However, I found a solution. While I couldn't change this from powershell. Adding the line pushd from inside the Bat file solved the problem of using relative paths for all nested bat files, and their nested functions.